# Armature before or after other modifiers?

Tags: animation, modifiers, rigging, armature

Generally speaking, when I have other modifiers, like `Solidify` or `Skin`, should I put my `Armature` before or after them in the stack? For example, to animate a T-shirt that comes with:

[image]

What's the proper place for `Armature`? I know this problem is a bit opinion-based, but I suppose it's extremely common to have `Armature` and other modifiers at the same time, and I'd like to know what the common practice is.

Comment: I guess you should put it below the Mirror, as you want to parent your object as a full symmetrical object, then keep the Solidify and Subdivision below the Armature

Comment: i personally think this is not opinion-based because if you change the order the result is different!

Comment: The order depends on your goal.  You probably want mirror, armature, solidify, subdiv but various orders do various things, and it's impossible to give any advice without know what you're modifying-- without knowing details for this particular situation.  There's no single order to use modifiers, only different orders depending on goals.  The way that can be known is not the eternal way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my old question here. When I submitted this question I was almost 100% newbie to animation. Now I've get a hang of it and I'll try to put my thoughts here.

The Armature modifier's only purpose is deforming the mesh. Unlike Armature, Mirror, Subdiv and Solidify generate additional geometry. So the real question is whether you want to deform these generated geometry or not. If you want to deform the geometry generated by modifier X, you need to put armature after X.